# Fetching and summing data from database - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a record in my database which looks like the below

**Table**

```
id   client_id   to_pay  due   session 
 1     12         100     50     ***
 2     24         80      30     ***
 3     12          0      10     ***
 4     24          0       5     ***
```

Now in my query below, i want to fetch all data from the table above by grouping the data according to the client_id but in the query also, i need to sum up `to_pay` and `due` for each client in the response.

How do i get this done please ?

**Controller**

```
   public function collectionPost(Request $request)
    {

        $fees = Collection::select('*')
        ->where('session',$request->get('session'))->groupby('client_id')->sum('due')
        ->get();

        return $fees;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error ? would be helpful to know. we would know if your database is in strict mode or not.

Comment: this code only returns only the summation of `due` @N69S. But i want other details of the clients to be in the response as well since i am using select (*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the method `sum` it overwrites the `select` to get the right result.

You can build your select without using the `sum` method.

```php
$fees = Collection::select(DB::raw('SUM(due) as total_due'), DB::raw('SUM(to_pay) as total_to_pay'))
        ->where('session',$request->get('session'))->groupby('client_id')
        ->get();

        return $fees;
```

And add more to your select.